# How to delete text within most outer loop

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to delete all text that include a link within outermost parentheses on a web page using regex in python but to no avail.

I tried out some regex patterns such as the one below:

```
paragraph = re.sub(r'\(.*[<a]+\)', '', p)
```

where i'm trying to check if the  tag exists between the outermost parentheses.

In this example from wikipedia:

```
    Rwanda (/ruˈɑːndə, -ˈæn-/ (About this soundlisten); Kinyarwanda: U Rwanda [u.ɾɡwaː.nda] (About this soundlisten)), officially the Republic of Rwanda (Kinyarwanda: Repubulika y'u Rwanda; Swahili: Jamhuri ya Rwanda; French: République du Rwanda) , is a country in Central ...
```

input text:

```
'<p><b>Rwanda</b> (<span class="nowrap"><span class="IPA nopopups noexcerpt"><a href="/wiki/Help:IPA/English" title="Help:IPA/English">/<span style="border-bottom:1px dotted"><span title="\'r\' in \'rye\'">r</span><span title="/u/: \'u\' in \'influence\'">u</span><span title="/ˈ/: primary stress follows">ˈ</span><span title="/ɑː/: \'a\' in \'father\'">ɑː</span><span title="\'n\' in \'nigh\'">n</span><span title="\'d\' in \'dye\'">d</span><span title="/ə/: \'a\' in \'about\'">ə</span></span>, <wbr/>-<span style="border-bottom:1px dotted"><span title="/ˈ/: primary stress follows">ˈ</span><span title="/æ/: \'a\' in \'bad\'">æ</span><span title="\'n\' in \'nigh\'">n</span></span>-/</a></span> <span class="nowrap" style="font-size:85%"><bracket><span class="unicode haudio"><span class="fn"><span style="white-space:nowrap;margin-right:.25em;"><a href="/wiki/File:Rwanda_pronunciation.ogg" title="About this sound"><img alt="About this sound" data-file-height="20" data-file-width="20" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/11px-Loudspeaker.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/17px-Loudspeaker.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/22px-Loudspeaker.svg.png 2x" width="11"/></a></span><a class="internal" href="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rwanda_pronunciation.ogg" title="Rwanda pronunciation.ogg">listen</a></span></span>)</span></span>; <a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Kinyarwanda_language" title="Kinyarwanda language">Kinyarwanda</a>:  <small></small><span class="IPA" title="Representation in the International Phonetic Alphabet <bracket>IPA)"><a href="/wiki/Help:IPA" title="Help:IPA">[u.ɾɡwaː.nda]</a></span> <span class="nowrap" style="font-size:85%"><bracket><span class="unicode haudio"><span class="fn"><span style="white-space:nowrap;margin-right:.25em;"><a href="/wiki/File:Rwanda_<bracket>rw)_pronunciation.ogg" title="About this sound"><img alt="About this sound" data-file-height="20" data-file-width="20" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/11px-Loudspeaker.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/17px-Loudspeaker.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Loudspeaker.svg/22px-Loudspeaker.svg.png 2x" width="11"/></a></span><a class="internal" href="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Rwanda_%28rw%29_pronunciation.ogg" title="Rwanda <bracket>rw) pronunciation.ogg">listen</a></span></span>)</span>), officially the <b>Republic of Rwanda</b> <bracket><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Kinyarwanda_language" title="Kinyarwanda language">Kinyarwanda</a>: ; <a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Kiswahili" title="Kiswahili">Swahili</a>: ; <a href="/wiki/French_language" title="French language">French</a>: ), is a country  in <a href="/wiki/Central_Africa" title="Central Africa">Central</a> ... </p>'
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
Rwanda, officially the Republic of Rwanda ...
```

However; it fails where it gets all text from the first opening parenthesis until the last opening parenthesis instead of getting the first set of outer parentheses.

Can I do this using regex or do I have to look somewhere else?

Comment: how about using a proper XML/HTML parser when dealing with web pages? As that would be the right way

Comment: I am doing an assignment where i'm solving the getting to philosophy problem using python.

Comment: please give clear input -> desired output

Comment: done, please check it out.

Comment: @amro_ghoneim Can you use BeautifulSoup? Are the parentheses always balanced, e.g. no `text (inside(more inside) more text`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I can use BeautifulSoup yes. I believe they are always balanced yes. I am working with Wikipedia pages only.

Comment: For max 2 level of nesting (1 more than your sample) try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/97QDlo/2).

Comment: @bobblebubble This solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to convert this problem to something like parsing HTML page (this assumes that parentheses are balanced):

```
s = '''
Rwanda (/ruˈɑːndə, -ˈæn-/ (About this soundlisten); Kinyarwanda: U Rwanda [u.ɾɡwaː.nda] (About this soundlisten)), officially the Republic of Rwanda (Kinyarwanda: Repubulika y'u Rwanda; Swahili: Jamhuri ya Rwanda; French: République du Rwanda)
'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = re.sub(r'\(', r'<bracket>', s)
s = re.sub(r'\)', r'</bracket>', s)

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
for bracket in soup.select('bracket'):
    bracket.extract()

s = re.sub(r'\s+,', r',', soup.body.text.strip())

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Rwanda, officially the Republic of Rwanda
```

Comment: This is great, but the thing is that i'm aiming to delete all text within parentheses if this text contains a link as I want the first link that is not inside parentheses for future use. Your answer, when I convert it back to a soup object, becomes all text within the main tags and discards the <a> tags as well. Hope i'm making any sense.

Comment: @amro_ghoneim Can you provide example of input text? You can edit your question and put it there.

Comment: I just did, please check it out. what I want is to delete all text within parentheses that has links within them so that I can get the first link outside parentheses (in this case Central Africa).